# Expression must evaluate to node set in Xpath error while trying to get value

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I am getting error while trying to get nodes which has value of Home and Auto.
Any help is appreciated.

```
XElement coverage = vehicle.XPathSelectElement("s0:VehicleCoverage/s0:Coverages/[CoverageLimitName=('Auto' |'Home')]", namespaceManager);
```

I like to fetch nodes under

```
<Coverages>
  <Coverage>
    <CoverageLimitName>Home</CoverageLimitName>
    <OptionalCode1>WY</OptionalCode1>
    <OptionalCode2>Bodily Injury</OptionalCode2>
    </CoverageLimitValue>
    <Premium>166.00</Premium>
  </Coverage>
  <Coverage>
    <CoverageLimitName>Auto</CoverageLimitName>
    <CoverageLimitValue>
      <OptionalCode1>T</OptionalCode1>
      <OptionalCode2>Property Damage</OptionalCode2>
    </CoverageLimitValue>
    <Premium>88.00</Premium>
  </Coverage>
  <Coverage>
  </Coverage>
  ....
  </Coverage>
</Coverages>
```

I would like to use xpath only and would like to fetch entire coverage tag when it has CoverageLimitName as home and auto

Comment: Please edit your question and show what precisely you expect as the result of your XPath expression, given the XML document you show. Also, the expression and the document contradict each other because there are prefixed element names in the XPath expression, but not in the document.

Comment: Yes, as @MathiasMüller says, include the XML document that is correct with regard to namespaces and structure, otherwise we can only guess the correct structure.

Comment: Also, your XML is actually not valid as it is shown in the question - the first `Coverage` element has a closing `CoverageLimitValue` tag but no opening tag. Posting a question with invalid XML as an example makes it hard for people to assist you.

Comment: @MathiasMüller : Edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My educated guess is that you want the following:

```
/s0:VehicleCoverage/s0:Coverages/s0:Coverage[s0:CoverageLimitName = 'Auto' or s0:CoverageLimitName = 'Home']
```

Which, for the document you show, would return both `Coverage` elements. (Given that the namespaces are properly dealt with.)

We have to guess because your sample XML document lacks a namespace declaration and because you did not tell us what exactly you are looking for.