# How to fetch value against list of strings from xml using linq and xpath?

Tags: c#, xml, linq, xpath

I have the following list

```
List<string> vehicles = new List<string> {"Year", "Make", "Model" };
```

And I am fetching a node `<Vehicle>` from a huge xml using

```
var vehicle = xdoc.XPathSelectElements("s0:Transport/s0:Vehicles/s0:Vehicle[s0:Insured='Y']", namespaceManager).ToList();
```

I am trying to get year, make and model from the vehicle node :

```
var vehicleList = vehicle.Where(x => vehicles.Contains(x.Name.LocalName)).ToList();
```

But it is returning `null` value for `vehicleList`. Can anyone please correct my query?

Xml sample is

```
 <Transport>
 .....
 <Vehicles>
      <Vehicle>
        <Insured>Y</Insured>
        <Number>1</Number>
        <Year>1997</Year>
        <ComprehensiveSymbol />
        <Make>FORD</Make>
        <Model>F-250 HEAVY DUTY</Model>
        <BodyStyle>PICKUP</BodyStyle>
        <VehicleType>C</VehicleType>
        <UseType>
          <V4Code i:nil="true" />
          <SourceCode>1</SourceCode>
          -----

     </Vehicle>
</Vehicles>

---
--
</Transport>
```

Comment: Can you show some sample of your XML? It's not possible to help without that.

Comment: The same problem as in your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34272851/1987598): Please include a [minimal, **complete** and verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) sample of your input XML document. Do not add this document as a comment, edit your question instead.

Comment: What you are trying to do exactly? Fetch all the nodes present in `vehicles`?

Comment: Fetch only the elements given in the list

Comment: I can only repeat myself: show a complete, accurate input document. The XPath expression you show suggests that there is a _namespace_ in the input document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have understood you correctly then I will do it with `LINQ-to-XML` rather like this:-

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load("XMLFile");
var vehicleList = xdoc.Root.Descendants("Vehicle")
                                       .Where(x => (string)x.Element("Insured") == "Y")
                                       .Elements()
                                       .Where(x => vehicles.Any(z => z == x.Name));
```

This will return `IEnumerable<XElement>` which you can iterate with `foreach` loop. Also if you want to retrieve the value directly then you can project the value like this (at the end) - `.Select(x => (string)x)` which will return `IEnumerable<string>`.

Comment: Its returning null values :(

Comment: @CuriousDev - Are you sure you don't have any whitespace in your XML element name? And yes do you have any namespace in your XML? It will make a huge difference.

Comment: @CuriousDev You might not be aware of this, but namespaces are important. This is what a default namespace declaration looks like: `<Transport xmlns="http://www.transport.com">`. Do you see something similar in your XML document? Then please show this declaration.

Comment: @RahulSingh : Yes ji.Thank you

Comment: @CuriousDev Even though you accept answers, I must say you are really most unhelpful. If you are looking for help on this site, please answer our questions and include _all_ necessary information, especially when people explicitly tell you what is missing. Please keep this in mind for future questions. (An upvote for your effort, Rahul, btw!)